# Как при помощи файла .htaccess сделать так, что при определенном url контент будет браться из другого места?

Tags: .htaccess

У меня есть задача: есть сайт, в котором, например, при попадании на страницу /drive/123, контент будет браться из страницы /drive/ и так с любым url, который будет дочерним от /drive/ т.е "/drive/file", "/drive/example".
Общий принцип: "drive/..."
Как это реализовать при помощи .htaccess? На всякий случай ещё раз обращу внимание, что не должно быть редиректа на /drive/, url должен оставаться прежним.

Answer (score 0):

как-то так должно  быть

```
RewriteRule ^drive/.+ drive [L,QSA]
```